# No puedo editar el código de una librería externa en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, couchbase

Estoy usando la libreria de `CouchBase Lite` para sincronizar datos en `Android Studio`, el caso es que necesito modificar una linea de la librería debido a un [bug](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/issues/942)

Para importa la libreria hago, desde mi modulo app de gradle  :

```
compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.4.0'
```

Hasta aquí todo correcto.
Ahora busco la libreria, pare ello cambio la vista del proyecto del modo `Android` al `Project`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez encontrada la libreria , busco la clase que tengo que cambiar, hago doble click sobre ella para abrirla en Android studio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde tengo el problema, no puedo cambiar nada del código de la librería, no puedo escribir, tampoco borrar , solo verlo.
Alguna idea de como poder modificar el código de una clase compilada desde Gradle, o cualquier posible solución

**EDITO**

Estoy intentando importar la librería desde Github , Según puedo leer en [aquí](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-java-core) la librería esta divida en dos partes;

> couchbase-lite-java-core

Esta primera librería la estoy importando con New-> Import->module -> navego hacia el archivo donde me he descargo la librería y la importo. Hago los mismo para la segunda parte:

> couchbase-lite-android

Pero me aparece este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

No puedes editar una librería externa que ya ha sido compilada, de primeras. Pero si el creador tiene subido el código de la librería a algún repositorio como github puedes descargártelo y añadirlo como un módulo local. De esta forma si te permitirá editarla.

Aquí tienes un paso a paso en inglés de como se hace:
[Como añadir una librería local a tu proyeto en Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio/16639227#16639227)

Answer (score 0):

**No puedes realizar edición al código de la dependencia!**.

En este caso puedes realizar un [fork](https://github.com/Jorgesys/couchbase-lite-android) que es una copia del proyecto en el cual puedes realizar modificaciones.

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android

Realizas la corrección del bug y puedes pedir permiso para subir el cambio siendo un [contribuidor](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/graphs/contributors) del proyecto.

Comment: gracias, he añadido más información a la consulta. No voy a poder corregirlo porque es un valor booleano lo que tengo que modificar, no es un bug en si

Comment: En que parte se encuentra y  que valor deseas recibir?

Comment: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/issues/942 es una clase que se llama ChangeTracker - simplest solution could be set usePOST variable in ChangeTracker false.